# Is there a timer available in Yii?

Tags: timer, yii

I am now using the framework Yii to develop a website and I need to use a timer to limit the access time of a certain page but I do not know what to do with it. Namely, when a user is filling up a form, he or she has to finish filling the form in a limitted period of time, otherwise he or she is not allowed to fill up the rest of the form. I wonder what should I do and where I can find a timer to meet my need? Thanks a lot.

Comment: write start time to session variable when starting form and check against it if submitted. Also add javascript snippet to automatically submit just before expire.

Comment: So I can use a javascript snippet to automatically submit just before expire? That is what I want to do. Then what should I do if I want to use this method? I cannot write javascript now so I do not know the usage well, then how should I start learning it? Thank you.

Comment: @Timothy - If you're developing in PHP, you should certainly learn Javascript. JS is often the other half of the puzzle when building a web site. It's the mustard in the hotdog - without it you've just got a dry roll and sausage.

Comment: Thank you, mwotton. I have solved this problem using JS. In the past I do not know a lot of web site and I had thought that PHP is enough, until I found that Javascript could help a lot. Sorry for not replying ASAP and I have solved the problem using Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no timer available in Yii. Use sessions on server side as @Imre L suggests.

Comment: I see and I took @Imre L's advice and used JS in the web site. Now the problem has been solved and thank you for your kind help.